# How to get number of records in Parquet file

Tags: apache-pig, parquet

I have a parquet file created from text /dat file using Pig Script.

Now i would like to know how many records in the parquet file without reading the file?

Is there anyway, Parquet file stores the number of rows somewhere in meta-data?

Answer (score 0):

Read from the path using `parquet.pig.ParquetLoader`.  Then the parqet file will be a normal file and then you can go for a count of the records.

```
LOGS = LOAD '/X/Y/abc.parquet' USING parquet.pig.ParquetLoader ;

LOGS_GROUP= GROUP LOGS ALL;

LOG_COUNT = FOREACH LOGS_GROUP GENERATE COUNT_STAR(LOGS);

dump LOG_COUNT;
```